# How to dynamically update template in component of Angular 2, Ionic 2

Tags: angular, templates, compilation, ionic2

I have a component that gets its template from a remote url. I want to have a function on event which does something to request the component's template again and change the already rendered template.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'cartpage-blocks-cartpage',
  templateUrl: '/url/to/romote/server/template'
})

export class CartPageBlocksCartPage{

  /**
   * Constructor of class
   *
   * @param events - events controller
   */
  constructor(
    public events: Events
  ){
     this.events.subscribe('reload-component-template', () => {
        /* Do something to reload template */
     });
  }
}
```

How to request component template again and recompile the template to a newer updated one? I want it because, after my user is authorised, my template automatically changes and I want to show changes dynamically by calling an event.

Comment: you are trying server side rendering in ionic 2?

Comment: Yes, it is. Rendering is on remote server with using of sessions to show same additional information.

Comment: AFAIK https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/support-for-angular-universal/49103/2 there is no support for angular universal(which is server side rendering for angular) in ionic 2 yet

Answer (score 0):

I think they have never intend to add dynamic swapping for templates, instead their recommended way is to have variables to swap the different views.

A better way is to work with your routes and creating specific component templates with conditional statements to show/hide different features. Make sure you set up AuthGuards to make sure that your app only allows authorised users.